# Finding the general solution to Bernoulli equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been asked to find the general solution of the following Bernoulli equation,

$x'(t)=\alpha x(t)-\beta x(t)^3$

where $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$ are constants.

I found the general solution to be

$x(t)=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt {\frac{\beta}{\alpha}+ce^{\alpha t}}}$

where c is the constant of integration.

However in the solution given by my lecturer the general solution is

$x(t)=\pm \frac{\sqrt{\alpha}e^{\alpha t}}{\sqrt {c{\alpha}+\beta e^{2\alpha t}}}$

To find my solution I first divided the initial equation by $x(t)^3$. Then I let $z(t)=x(t)^{-2}$ and substituted it into my equation. Then I used the Integrating Factor technique to solve the equation and back substituted $|{x(t)}|=z(t)^{1/2}$ to get my general solution.

Would it be an error in calculations that led me to get the incorrect solution or was my method fundamentally incorrect? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: $$ |{x(t)}|=z(t)^{-1/2}  $$

Comment: "Would it be an error in calculations that led me to get the incorrect solution" Perhaps it may be better if you actually show the calculation process so we can easily identify the steps where you've gone wrong. Your lecturer's solution is indeed correct.

Comment: Firstly, after your substitution, did you get:
$$\frac{dz}{dt}+2\alpha z=2\beta$$
If so, did you get the integrating factor $\mu(t)=e^{\int 2a~dt}=e^{2at}$ to obtain:
$$e^{2\alpha t}\frac{dz}{dt}+2\alpha e^{2\alpha t}z=2\beta e^{2\alpha t}$$
If so, you are on the right track.

Comment: No my substitution is wrong I have $\frac{dz}{dt}-\alpha z = -\beta$ after substitution. I'm guessing just by looking at the difference that I should have multiplied across by -2 when subbing $z(t)$ in?

Comment: @B.K97 Possibly your evaluation of $\frac{dz}{dt}$ could have been wrong. I've made an answer, so you may be able to spot yoir mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a separable equation, but since you mentioned Bernoulli equation, I supposed that you want a solve in this way. You have:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\alpha x-\beta x^3 \tag{1}$$
Let's subtract both sides by $\alpha x$ and divide both sides by $x^3$:
$$\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}}{x^3}-\frac{\alpha}{x^2}=-\beta \tag{2}$$

Then, we must substitute $z(t)=\frac{1}{x^2}$. This gives $\frac{dz}{dt}=-\frac{2\frac{dx}{dt}}{x^3}$. Note that we can put $(2)$ in the form of the substitution by multiplying both sides by $-2$.
$$-\frac{2\frac{dx}{dt}}{x^3}+\frac{2\alpha}{x^2}=2\beta \tag{3}$$
After substituting, we obtain:
$$\frac{dz}{dt}+2\alpha z=2\beta \tag{4}$$
I think you can continue from here. If not, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot I think I have it now

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in your solution which should be 
$$x(t)=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt {\frac{\beta}{\alpha}+ce^{{\color{red}{-2}}\alpha t}}}$$
$-2$ was missing.

Now, it is the same as the lecturer's solution

$$x(t)=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt {\frac{\beta}{\alpha}+ce^{{\color{red}{-2}}\alpha t}}}
=\pm \frac{\sqrt{\alpha}e^{\alpha t}}{  \sqrt { \alpha e^{2\alpha t}\left(  \frac{\beta}{\alpha}+ce^{{\color{red}{-2}}\alpha t}\right)}}
=\pm \frac{\sqrt{\alpha}e^{\alpha t}}{\sqrt {c{\alpha}+\beta e^{2\alpha t}}}$$

Comment: Wasn't a typo I made a mistake earlier on in the question when doing  substitution

Comment: So, you found where was the mistake. All's well that ends well.